# Pericyclic Reaction

Tags: pericyclic

Does anyone know what PhMe is used for in this reaction (how it contributes to the mechanism?)? I thought pericyclic reactions only needed heat? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Heard about solvents?

Comment: Is there any reason for that particular one?

Comment: Again @Zhe, have you thought about converting to an answer?

Answer (score 1):

PhMe is methylbenzene, better known as toluene.

Toluene is a very common nonpolar, organic solvent. As a simple aromatic solvent, it is [preferred over benzene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benzene#Early_applications), which is known to be carcinogenic.

In your example, it's a good solvent because it (a) dissolves both reactants quite easily and (b) has a high boiling point (about $110\ ^{\circ}\mathrm{C}$). The higher boiling point allows the reaction to be heated to a higher temperature, which helps the reaction go faster.